# Search for a match, copy entire row, and paste to corresponding

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

Col B on "Sheet2" contains 370 rows of data.
Starting with "Sheet2" Cell B1, I want to search for a matching value in Col B on "Sheet1" (it could be located anywhere in the first 300 rows of "Sheet1" Col B).
If a match is found, copy the entire row from "Sheet1" and paste to Row1 on "Sheet2".  Then, move to "Sheet2" Cell B2 and repeat the search, this time pasting the entire row from "Sheet1" to Row2 on "Sheet2".  Continue moving thru the entire column of data on "Sheet2", searching for each cell's value on "Sheet1".  If a search doesn't return a match, then do not paste anything to that row on "Sheet2" and just proceed to search for the next cell on "Sheet2". (For example, if Sheet1 Col B doesn't contain a match for Sheet2 Cell B3, then nothing gets pasted in Sheet2 Row3.)

I have found the following example, which starts to help me, but it specifies the search value and doesn't loop thru the entire column of values like I am attempting to do.

```
Sub CopyYes()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    J = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
    For Each c In Source.Range("E1:E1000")   ' Do 1000 rows
        If c = "yes" Then
           Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Range.Find`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, and do it fast:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyYes()

    'You need Microsoft Scripting Runtime library under Tools-References for this
    Dim arrPaste As Variant: arrPaste = Sheet2.UsedRange.Value
    Dim arrCopy As Variant: arrCopy = Sheet1.UsedRange.Value
    Dim MyMatches As New Dictionary: Set MyMatches = CreateDictionary(arrCopy)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrPaste)
        If arrPaste(i, 2) = vbNullString Then Exit For
        If MyMatches.Exists(arrPaste(i, 2)) Then PasteData arrPaste, arrCopy, i, MyMatches(arrPaste(i, 2))
    Next i
    Sheet2.UsedRange.Value = arrPaste
    Erase arrCopy
    Erase arrPaste

End Sub
Private Function CreateDictionary(arr As Variant) As Dictionary

    Dim i As Long
    Set CreateDictionary = New Dictionary
    For i = 1 To 300
        CreateDictionary.Add arr(i, 2), i
    Next i

End Function
Private Sub PasteData(arrPaste As Variant, arrCopy As Variant, i As Long, MyMatch As Long)

    Dim j As Long
    For j = 1 To UBound(arrCopy, 2)
        If arrCopy(MyMatch, j) = vbNullString Then Exit For
        arrPaste(i, j) = arrCopy(MyMatch, j)
    Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: I get "Compile error: Duplicate declaration in current scope for 'arr As Variant'...

Comment: Sorry @DaveF wanted to update the code and forgot that. The code is edited now and it should be working.

Comment: Ok.  That seems to have fixed my first error (thanks!).  But now I'm getting "This key is already associated with an element of this collection " for the line 'CreateDictionary.Add arr(i,2), i'

Comment: That means exactly that, you have duplicates on your sheet1, in between your 300 rows there are duplicate values for column B.

Comment: @DaveF if it works, please consider marking the answer as final so it can close the topic.

Comment: It works.  Thanks!! But now I've realized that I will need to run this on files which may have as many as 1000 rows of data.  However, if I change the Private Function to read "For i = 1 To 1000" I get an error stating "Subscript out of range".  Is there any way to expand the scope of your code?

Comment: I realize now that I get the error if I set "i" to cover a range greater than the number of of rows of data.  However, I need to run this macro on several different workbooks, each having sheets with a different number of rows of data.  Is there any way to accommodate this (i.e. - ignore blanks in the range) so that I don't have to edit the range for "i" in each workbook?

Comment: Change the 300 or 1000 to `Ubound(arr)` but make sure to write an `Exit For` if the cell is empty to avoid big times on running the script.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `Range.Find` to search for your matching cell
2. Use a `Union` to create a collection of the rows that are found
3. Once your loop is finished, copy your range all at once **if** the `Union` is not empty

---

```
Sub Shelter_In_Place()

Dim Source As Worksheet: Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Target As Worksheet: Set Target = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim Found As Range, lr As Long
Dim CopyMe As Range

lr = Target.Range("B" & Target.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lr
    Set Found = Source.Range("B:B").Find(Target.Range("B" & i), LookIn:=xlWhole)

    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        If Not CopyMe Is Nothing Then
            Set CopyMe = Union(CopyMe, Target.Range("B" & i))
        Else
            Set CopyMe = Target.Range("B" & i)
        End If
    End If

    Set Fouund = Nothing
Next i

If Not CopyMe Is Nothing Then
    CopyMe.EntireRow.Copy
    Source.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a "subscript out of range" error for the line 'Set Found = Source.Range("B:B").Find(Target.Range("B" & i), LookIn:=xlWhole)'...